# Is it possible to convert a char** to a char* in C?

Tags: c, arrays, char

When I made one of my programs that goes through a string, I made it work with variables of the type char*. However I found out that I need to pass it a variable of the type char**.

Everything would work perfectly if I could convert `char** line` into `char* line`. Is there a way to do this?

edit: here's the top part of my code. This works for fine for char* variables, but I can't get my final product to work unless I can pass in a `char** line` and convert it to a `char*`

```
int exiting(char* line, int argcptr){
   printf("char* line = %s\n", line);
   int words = argcptr;
   char* linecpy = (char*) malloc(100); 
   char* arg1 = " ";
   char* arg2 = " ";
   strcpy(linecpy, line);

   char* bin = strtok(linecpy, " "); //obtain the first word

   if(words > 1){
      linecpy += (strlen(bin) + 1); 
      arg1 = strtok(linecpy, " ");  //the next word will be the first argument, if applicable
      printf("arg1 = %s\n", arg1);
      words--;
   }
   if(words > 1){
      linecpy += (strlen(arg1) + 1); 
      arg2 = strtok(linecpy, " "); //if applicable, grab the third argument
   }


   //***exit [value]*** :  exit the shell with the value. if no value given, exit with value 0.
   if(strcmp(bin, "exit") == 0){

      if(strcmp(arg1, " ") == 0){
         printf("exiting with 0\n");
         exit(0);
      }
      else{
         int exitNum = atoi(arg1);
         printf("exiting with %d\n", exitNum); 
         exit(exitNum);
      }
   }
   ...
```

Comment: If the reason for the `**` is so the function can change the pointer passed by the caller, then the answer is yes.

Comment: [mcve], please.

Comment: Depends on what the `*`s mean in context.  Does the function return a `char*` as a ref/out parameter, or does it take an array of `char*`s as input?

Comment: @DavidBowling, updated my question.

Comment: @dan04 currently, it takes an input of type `char*` and works fine. I need to change this so that it takes in a `char**` because one of my other functions returns a `char**`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a function like this:

```
void doSomething ( char ** linePtr ) {
    // ...
}
```

Then `linePtr` is a pointer to something that is a string pointer, so the caller may have called it like that:

```
char * string = ...;
doSomething(&string);
```

If you need a string pointer in your function, you just need to read the value the pointer points to:

```
void doSomething ( char ** linePtr ) {
    char * line = *linePtr;
    // ...
}
```

However note that `char **` may also be a pointer to an array of string pointers:

```
char ** strings[] = {
    "String1", "String2", "String3", "String4", NULL
};
doSomething(strings);
```

In that case you either need to know the array length:

```
void doSomething ( char ** linePtr, size_t arrayLength ) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        char * line = linePtr[i];
        // ...
    }
}
```

Or the array must be NULL terminated as shown above, then you can find its end by checking for NULL:

```
void doSomething ( char ** linePtr ) {
    for (size_t i = 0; linePtr[i]; i++) {
        char * line = linePtr[i];
        // ...
    }
}
```

Here's some more pointer magic:

```
char c = 5;
char * cptr = &c; // `cptr` is the address of `c`
char ** cptrptr = &cptr; // `cptrptr` is the address of `cptr`

char * anotherCptr = *cptrptr; // `anotherCptr` is the address of `c`
char anotherC = *anotherCptr; // `anotherC` is now 5.

*cptr = 8; // Now `c` is `8`

char c2 = 12;
cptr = &c2;
*cptr = 16; // `c2` is now `16` but `c` has not changed again.
**cptrptr = 2; // `c2` is now 2. Why? As `cptrptr` still points to `cptr`,
// the fact that `cptr` points elsewhere now won't influence `cptrptr`.

char * aString = calloc(sizeof(char), 100); // 100 characters in memory
char ** aStringPtr = &aString;
char * anotherString = *aStringPtr; // `anotherString == aString`
// They both point to the same piece of memory now. When changing
// `anotherString[0]`, `aString[0]` changes as well.
```

Also note that pointers and arrays are often interchangeable in C, that's because arrays in C have no metadata, so an array in memory with just a single value is in fact just a single value:

```
char ca = 5;
char cb[1] = { 5 }; // The memory of `ca` and the one `cb` points to look identical!
char * captr = &ca;
char * cbptr = cb; // No `&`, as an array reference is a pointer.
char c = *captr; // Works.
c = captr[0]; // Works, too, albeit `ca` is no array!
c = cbptr[0]; // Works.
c = *cbptr;   // Works, too, albeit `cb` is an array!
```

In fact, array subscription in C is syntactical sugar. Instead of `x[n]` you can always write `*(x+n)` and it will have an identical effect. Note that `+` on a pointer does not move the pointer by `n` bytes, it moves the pointer by *n times the size of x* (`<addr> + (n * sizeof(x))`). So a `char  *` pointer can be a pointer to a single `char` or it can be a pointer to an array of char values (`char[]`), you cannot tell in C.

Answer (score 1):

The `char **` pointer becomes the `char *` when you dereference it.

For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 10

int main(void) {

    char **ppchar = malloc(sizeof(char *) * N);

    *ppchar = malloc(100); // now it is a char *pointer and I allocate the memory for the chars

    strcpy (*ppchar, "Hello world"); 

    printf("the char string = %s\n", *ppchar);  // referenced char ** pointer is char * now
    printf("and the actual chars. First = %c and fourth = %c\n", *(*ppchar + 0), *(*ppchar + 3));
}
```

`*(*ppchar + 0)` === `**ppchar`.

You can play with it yourself https://ideone.com/qv6w7n